# Bar chart that doesn't start at zero

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1

It's a super simple bar chart with one bar

The y axis shows values from 0-200

The values for the bar are start at 50 and finish at 150 so I wanted to draw the bars at these values so the bar would be somewhere in the center of the graph.

I sort of have the height but can't fix the y position.

Comment: in line 45: `.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + -40 + ")")`

Comment: This positions the start correctly but how do I get the height to create the correct finish position - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-vobziu?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1

Comment: see the last line how he has calculated the height. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: This doesn't seem to give me the correct height - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-u6qh2j?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the range going from `0` to `height`...

```
scale.range([0, height])
```

...or from `height` to `0`...

```
scale.range([height, 0])
```

...but this doesn't change the fact that, in an SVG, the coordinates system of the `y` axis goes from the top to the bottom of the page. Therefore, the `y` attribute has to be always **smaller** than the `height` for a rectangle.

That being said, you have to use `finish` for the `y` attribute:

```
.attr("y", function (d, i) {
    return y(d.finish);
})
.attr("height", function(d,i){
    return y(d.start) - y(d.finish);
});
```

Here is the updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-qnk7bl?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks for your help again Gerardo, it doesn't seem to work if I add more data https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-7mcbbr?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1

Comment: It doesn't work with one set of data if the values are different - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-wk1rss?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: Check it again: https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-vowdyx?file=index.js